# I m trying to deploy AspectJ in Spring MVC servlet but got an exception on server startup

Tags: spring-mvc, aspectj

Exception on Server

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdv
isor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotat
ion.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transac
tionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.Bean
CreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transactio
n.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean fai
led; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: C
ould not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy73]: Common causes of thi
s problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception i
s java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy73

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetriev
alHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyC
reator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAuto
ProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:8
5)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProx
yCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.
postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFa
ctory.java:890)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransact
ionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.sp
ringframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclas
s of class [class $Proxy73]: Common causes of this problem include using a final
 class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentExce
ption: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy73
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not gener
ate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy73]: Common causes of this problem incl
ude using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.Il
legalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy73
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProx
y.java:217)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.
java:111)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.
createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.
wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.
postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFa
ctory.java:409)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class
 $Proxy73
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:
446)
        at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.genera
teClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(Defa
ultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(Abstract
ClassGenerator.java:216)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:3
77)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProx
y.java:205)
        ... 93 more

        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.jav
a:1706)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:213)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:208)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD
river.java:35)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class
 $Proxy73
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:
446)
        at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.genera
teClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(Defa
ultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(Abstract
ClassGenerator.java:216)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:3
```

Comment: This question is still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should

1. not just post callstacks here but actually ask a question which can be answered by the community. Otherwise you keep us guessing what you might want to know.
2. read the exception before asking what it means because it clearly says so in this case.
3. search for similar problems here before posting.

Adding some line breaks into the relevant part of your call stack, it says:

```
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException:
    Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy73]:
    Common causes of this problem include using a final class or
    a non-visible class; nested exception is
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
            Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy73
```

So obviously you are trying to weave code into a final class, which CGLIB is uncapable of (when used indirectly from Spring AOP). Probably your Spring configuration somehow indicates that proxies of proxies should be generated. Maybe [SpringMVC Proxy issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063320/springmvc-proxy-issue) helps you solve your problem. I am no Spring user, BTW. So if you cannot solve your problem by yourself with my hints, you need to edit the question and add more info to it, such as the aspect code, the Spring configuration and whatever else might be helpful.